# How to make sure that certain digits in a number are not the same

Tags: regex, position

I have a couple of number strings like the following:

```
0000000
0000011
0000012
```

I want to validate that the pattern is like this:

```
AAAAABC
```

where `A`, `B` and `C` are all different digits. So in the example, only `0000012` should be matched.

My regex so far is `(\d)\1\1\1\1\d\d`, but it doesn't make sure that the digits are different. What do I need to do?

Comment: You mean that the regex works for you already? It seems that it won't work for the position B/C condition

Comment: I might be able to fix it, or explain... if you clarify

Comment: (\d)\1\1\1\1\d\d capture all those pattern. I want B and C and A value cannot be the same number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want

```
(\d)\1{4}(?!\1)(\d)(?!\1|\2)\d
```

**Explanation:**

```
(\d)       # Match a digit, capture in group 1
\1{4}      # Match the same digit as before four times
(?!\1)     # Assert that the next character is not the same digit as before
(\d)       # Match another digit, capture in group 2
(?!\1|\2)  # Assert the next character is different from both previous digits
\d         # Match another digit.
```

See it on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/mP4rM0).

Comment: @TimPietzcker 0000001 this pattern also supported.. B and A position also cannot be same.

Comment: @Sh4m: No, this regex doesn't match 0000001.